# Solr and Timecode information

Tags: solr

did anybody know, how we can keep timecode information (PAL) as it is in DB to pub solr. IN DB TC is in this format:

1997-05-24T16:27:47.800 PAL

but when we deploy it to solr, solr interpret it in zulu timestamp:

1997-05-24T14:27:47.8Z

Is there a cfg or a workaround to store in solr a tc as it is?

br

Francois

Comment: Do you mean time zone? Timecodes are usually relative, and is used for stuff like subtitles, etc.

Comment: No, i mean timecode, my timecode is declared as PAL and is a fix timecode for start of material. But solr changed these fixed value to lokal timezone.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you are using schemaless mode that automatically determines field types. It is sometimes useful to get started with, but the detection is not perfect. It is not recommended for production.

The easiest way to get around it is explicitly to define the field type. In your case, it seems you just want it to be a string instead of auto-detected date. So, you can delete (in Admin UI or via API) the auto-created field and recreate it as a string yourself manually.

Comment: Well, it is a managed schema and the field is declared as date, so i changed it to tdate first with same results. Then i tried as string and it failed once more. So maybe the database procedures writes it wrong to solr?!

Comment: You need to reindex your data after you change the type. Also, if you changed it in the schema file, you need to reload the core before reindexing. Possibly deleting all values too. It may help to just setup a seper-minimal separate example with several definitions and just index the same thing into all 3 fields and compare.